# How are peers supposed to be selected?

Tags: united-kingdom, political-appointments, house-of-lords

There are questions about appointment of Evgeny Lebedev to the house of Lords as a life peer.  The decision has been defended in a number of different ways:

- [Boris Johnson](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2022-03-07/johnson-denies-overruling-security-advice-to-make-lebedev-a-lord)

  - Johnson told reporters in London on Monday it would “obviously be extraordinary” if the security services had deemed Lebedev to be a risk and the prime minister had intervened to ensure the appointment was granted, “but that’s not the case.”
- [Michael Gove](https://news.sky.com/story/michael-gove-defends-boris-johnson-meeting-oligarch-evgeny-lebedev-who-mi6-had-concerns-about-12565036)

  - I think one of the things that Vladimir Putin would like us to do is to have an approach in the UK that said that everyone of Russian ancestry was somehow persona non grata.
- [Evgeny Lebedev](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-60765665)

  - I am not a security risk to this country, which I love. My father a long time ago was a foreign intelligence agent of the KGB, but I am not some agent of Russia.

All these seem to be 'negative reasons', in that they are why we should not exclude him from the house of Lords.  None of them are 'positive reasons', in that why this particular individual should be elevated to a life peerage.  From the point of view of a voter I would hope that the decision was made because they were considered the best person to make the laws under which we all have to live.

Is there any rule, custom or expectation that peerages are assigned on the basis of ability to make good laws?  Is there anything that is supposed to guide these assignments, other that 'not an overt security risk'?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Peerage in this way is basically [a minor noble title](https://www.parliament.uk/site-information/glossary/peer/). It's not transferrable, nor hereditary so the only way to be made a peer like this is by the current monarch deciding to do so.

The custom or expectation is that such ennoblings are performed

> ...on the advice of the Prime Minister...

Which means a member of Parliament has concluded that this person should be a peer.  Whether or not you find that compelling, or an endorsement of the person's skills as a legislator is left as an exercise for the reader.

Boris Johnson isn't so much defending Lebedev's continuing to be a peer as he is defending his involvement in having advised the Queen to ennoble him in the first place.

Comment: It's actually a (somewhat) recent custom of its own for the Prime Minister to be guaranteed to be a sitting MP, rather than potentially a peer themselves, although the statute demanding an upper house almost exclusively consisting of life, rather than hereditary peers is newer.